# ASRock FM2A88M and NVMe support

Tags: nvme

Does this [ASRock FM2A88M](http://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/FM2A88M-HD+%20R3.0/index.asp) support NVMe disks?

If so, at what what maximum speed?

I'd asking this because I'd like to make an upgrade from a Kingston 128GB SSD, but don't know if this AMD motherboard supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a bit of research and I believe you cant because I have never found it explicitly stated. However i have not found anything that says it can't.

A few web sights I have used:

http://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/FM2A88M-HD+%20R3.0/?cat=Specifications

(This next sight was the one that did it for me if you go down to the slots row for the H110M-HDS, it explicitly states that it "Supports NVMe SSD as boot disks" however for the FM2A88M-HD+ R3.0 it doesn't bring it up.)

http://www.asrock.com/mb/compare.asp?SelectedModel=FM2A88M-HD%2B%20R3.0&SelectedModel=H110M-HDS&

Hope this helped